# How to have html files scanned by php as CGI?

Tags: php, html, cgi

I never worked with php as CGI so I have encounter a problem. I need execute php on html files. I tried to add instructions into .htaccess:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .htm .html
```

This didn't work:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 html
```

Nor did this:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html .phtml
```

I tried editing the httpd.conf by replacing

```
AddHandler cgi-scripts .cgi .pl .plx .ppl .perl
```

with

```
AddHandler cgi-scripts .cgi .pl .plx .ppl .perl .html
```

I then restarted apache, but this didn't help either.

Could you guide me to the right path?

Comment: Do you have php installed on your server?

Comment: Are you sure you are permitted to override those settings with .htaccess at all? Some hosting providers doesn't allow it - maybe yours is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what am I using at the moment for two different php versions: (in httpd.conf)

```
#PHP4 - for legacy projects
AddType application/x-httpd-php4 .php4 .php3 .phtml .inc
Action  application/x-httpd-php4 "/usr/local/php-4.4.4/bin/php-cgi"
<Directory /usr/local/php-4.4.4/bin>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

#PHP5 - default
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php .php5
Action  application/x-httpd-php5 "/usr/local/php-5.3.8/bin/php-cgi"
<Directory /usr/local/php-5.3.8/bin>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

As you can see there are 3 parts for each cgi handler:

1. bind extentsion to filetype
2. bind filetype to cgi handler
3. make sure directory where cgi executable resides is accessible

Answer (score 0):

You can find the instructions on how to configure the Apache web server for CGI scripts [in Apache's documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/howto/cgi.html).

On the page, they use Perl as the programming language for the CGI scripts, but the process is the same for every language.